# Which query is more efficient if I use complex expressions?

Tags: sql, odbc

Could any body tell which query is more efficient if I want to use the new computed columns to filter, aggregate and order data? The one uses nested selection or the one duplicate the expressions in one select clause? Is it database specified?

Query1:

`SELECT count(*), (age - 18) AS newcol FROM qmao_person WHERE (age - 18) > 0 GROUP BY (age - 18) ORDER BY (age - 18) DESC;`

Query2：

`SELECT count(*), s1.newcol FROM 
  (SELECT (age - 18) AS newcol FROM qmao_person) s1
WHERE s1.newcol > 0 GROUP BY s1.newcol ORDER BY s1.newcol DESC;`

BTW, the question is which query will be more efficinent instead of how to optimize the query.

Comment: What database platform? You have tagged this for SQLite and TSQL (SQL Server or Sybase?). But the general answer to questions like this is that instead of asking which one is more efficient, just try them both and measure their performance using the tools for that database platform. Doing this is not only a good learning experience, it gives you a better answer because no one else will have exactly the same data and system configuration as you. If you don't know *how* to measure their performance, that would certainly be something to ask here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query will produce identical results and beat both:

```
SELECT
    count(*),
    (age - 18) AS newcol
FROM qmao_person
WHERE age > 18
GROUP BY age
ORDER BY age DESC
```

But in general, answer to your question is very vendor specific.
If vendor uses heavy optimization - like factoring out common expressions or converting subselects into joins, it is very possible that results will be identical.

That said, I would still prefer first query of yours if I could not optimize it like I just did.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look on the execution of the two queries to see the difference. It depends on how the server optimizes them.
Example:
[Execution plan](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9990/SQL-Tuning-Tutorial-Understanding-a-Database-Execu)